# How to include std::vector, std::complex<double>, std::cout, etc. in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, std

I am new to Visual Studio for C++ (just moved in from Ubuntu g++ / gcc).
I am having trouble since Visual Studio does not seem to recognize
`std::vector`, `std::complex<>`, `std::complex<double>`, etc.
That all worked fine for Linux. How to do incorporate these in Visual Studio?

Comment: You do it the same way as in any C++ compiler, you just `#include` the according header. What did you do and what were the errors you got? See also [ask].

Comment: Assuming, of course, that the IDEs, compilers, and libraries are properly installed and configured.   But, if they are not, that's most likely a user problem, not a flaw  of particular products.

Comment: And how did your code look on Linux?

Comment: ok, i just got record time downvotes in a span of 1 minute, apparently i have to include <vector>, <complex>, etc. that did not need to be manually specified under the g++ compiler in linux

Comment: You need to include the header for any library type you use if you want portable code. It's all in a day's work

Comment: *"did not need to be manually specified under the g++"* [Huh?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/748f26192bd8d1eb)

Comment: Just include bits/stdc++.h

Comment: @RedFloyd - [No, no, most definitely not!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: @RedFloyd it won't even work for Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably copy pasted functions but forgot to include appropriate headers (newbie mistake).
Just try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pardon me but what problem is this answer solving? How is including vector different in visual studio than anywhere else?

Comment: I guess the problem was that he just copy-pasted functions but forgot to include appropriate headers. So this answer just hints that he should include the headers as well.